# Windows laptop wakes up automatically from sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, sleep, power

I am unable to put my Lenovo laptop in sleep. When I put it to sleep, it wakes automatically up within a minute, without me doing anything.

I checked even viewer. Below are the screen shots. It says `Reason: Power Button` in sixth screenshot, but I did not push it. Whats going on here?

I am running Windows 11 Home Single Language, 22H2, build 22621.2283

Screenshot 1
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

Screenshot 3
[image]

Screenshot 4
[image]

Screenshot 5
[image]

Screenshot 6
[image]

Screenshot 7
[image]

Screen shot 8 - no app seem to have waked the laptop:

[image]

Comment: Check if there is any Wake on ...  setting in BIOS.  Update Power Drivers and BIOS (UEFI), reset power management, restart and set it up, test.

Comment: Please [Generate and Analyze an Energy Report](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-energy-report/) and publish it online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: Check for `Power-Troubleshooter` events as well as `Kernel-Power`. They sometimes contain a more detailed `Wake Source` property. Usual suspects are Timer (scheduled tasks), or a network interface. Something like wiggling the mouse or reconnecting a peripheral may still show up as source "power button" or USB device as well depending on your hardware

Answer (score 0):

I last had that issue a few months back, in my case it was caused by the network device configuration being allowed to wake up the machine.

Below is the best article I could quickly find on how to disable that:
https://appuals.com/how-to-disable-allow-this-device-to-wake-the-computer/